# Vectors problem involving scalar multipliers.

Tags: vectors

[image]

(Sorry I have had to resort to images, I am unfamiliar with vectors in mathjax)

With this question, I can happily do part (a), but it is part (b) and part (c) I am struggling with. This is my current working:

[image]

However, this is not the correct answer, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The reflection in your lower image makes it difficult to read. Also, although it is trivial enough to figure out here, your working does not outline your thought process. Also, you may consider using $(a, b, c)$ or $\hat r$ notation.

Answer (score 1):

We first observe$$\overrightarrow{BC}=\overrightarrow{AC}-\overrightarrow{AB}=\frac13\overrightarrow{AB}=\binom{2}{-1}.$$For b note$$\overrightarrow{BP}=\frac12\overrightarrow{AP}=\binom{r/2}{p/2}\implies\overrightarrow{CP}=\overrightarrow{BP}-\overrightarrow{BC}=\binom{r/2-2}{p/2+1}.$$For c note that $$\overrightarrow{BP}=\overrightarrow{AP}-\overrightarrow{BP}=\overrightarrow{AB}=\binom{6}{-3}\implies\overrightarrow{CP}=\overrightarrow{BP}+\overrightarrow{AC}-\overrightarrow{AB}=\binom{8}{-4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hints.* You're told that the segment $AP$ is twice as long as $BP.$ You have a vector from $A$ to $P.$ You are asked for the vectors $\vec {BP}$ and $\vec {CP}.$

Note that $$\vec {AP}+\vec {PB}=\vec {AB}.$$ Since you know the first and last, you can find what you want, since it is opposite to the $\vec {PB}.$ Similarly, use the equality $$\vec {AC}+\vec {CP}=\vec {AP}$$ to find the $\vec {CP}.$ Hopefully you may now be able to do the third part (you'll likely need to use the fact that $AP=2BP$).